# Array find and replace based other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$data`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quarter] => Q1
            [category] => DEODORANTS,FACE CARE
            [fund_type] => EOT
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quarter] => Q2
            [category] => BODY CARE
            [fund_type] => A&P
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quarter] => Q2
            [category] => ORAL CARE,NOCATEGORY
            [fund_type] => A&P
        )

)
```

and other array `$categories`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [descriptions] => DEODORANTS
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [descriptions] => BODY CARE
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [descriptions] => FACE CARE
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [descriptions] => ORAL CARE
        )
)
```

I need to change value of `category` in `$data` with `id` from `$categories`:

code:

```
function lookup($data = array(), $categories = array())
{

  if(is_array($data))
  {

    foreach ($data as $k => $v)
    {

      $valCat = explode(',', $v['category']);

      if(!empty($valCat))
      {

        foreach ($valCat as $vc)
        {

          foreach ($categories as $c)
          {

            if($c['descriptions'] === $vc)
            {

              $CatID[] = $c['id'];

            }

          }

        }

      }

      $data[$k]['category'] = $CatID;

    }

    return $data;

  }

}
```

result `lookup($data, $categories)`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quarter] => Q1
            [category] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [fund_type] => EOT
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quarter] => Q2
            [category] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 2
                )

            [fund_type] => A&P
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quarter] => Q2
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => 4
                )

            [fund_type] => A&P
        )

)
```

correct result should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quarter] => Q1
            [category] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [fund_type] => EOT
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quarter] => Q2
            [category] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [fund_type] => A&P
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quarter] => Q2
                (
                    [0] => 4
                )

            [fund_type] => A&P
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not resetting the value of `$CatID`. After this line

```
foreach ($data as $k => $v)
{
```

add

```
    $CatID = array();
```